# How did the propellers attach on a Lazair attach if the shafts had a woodruff key instead of opposite thread?

Tags: aircraft-design, lazair

How did the propellers attach on a Lazair attach if the shafts had a woodruff key instead of opposite thread?

I understand the early Lazair prop shafts had a woodruff key.  How were
the props attached?

Don't you need opposite thread?

I assume you couldn't just use a cotter pin and a washer, as the props would try to shear off the cotter pins.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that while the original engine shafts had a slot for a woodruff key, no key was actually used in attaching the props to the crankshaft. Instead, a nominal arrangement of multiple (6, I believe) bolts attached the props to the crankshaft for mutual transmisal of both engine torque and prop thrust. Presumably the bolts were secured with safety wire, but I have no data on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to use a woodruff key to transmit thrust forces on a rotating shaft. Ideally you'd use a woodruff key to transmit the engine *torque* to the propeller, and use a separate clamp nut or series of bolts running through the crankshaft hub and the prop hub to prevent the propeller *thrust* from pulling the prop off the end of the engine crankshaft.

Comment: So... how did they attach the prop hub( if there was one)?  I'm thinking only 1 bolt at the end of a threaded hollow shaft... I think the standard practice is to thread a prob hub onto a threaded shaft with opposite thread, and then use bolts to attached the prop blades.